# How to use Zenity to display a files contents with tickboxes beside each line of the file

Tags: bash, ubuntu, zenity

Im trying to give a visual output for a file listing i have.  What i want to be able to do is display a tick box beside each line from the file

I have thrown together the following zenity command but my main problem is my file listings can be quite long.  From the command below i define the values by TRUE "" or FALSE ""

My question is can i read the contents and place them in the following command (or something similar) without having to make a massively long command

```
ans=$(zenity  --list  --text "Show List" --checklist  --column "Pick" --column "List" FALSE "BLAH" TRUE "Blah" FALSE "Blah2" FALSE "Blah3" --separator=":"); echo $ans
```

Regards

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# create an array with FALSE and lines from the file
unset list
while read -r line
do
    list+=("FALSE")
    list+=("$line")
done < data_file

# set some entries to TRUE
for entry in 0 2 5 11 12 19
do
    list[entry]="TRUE"
done

# display the dialog
ans=$(zenity --list --text "Show List" --checklist --column "Pick" --column "List" "${list[@]}" --separator=":")
echo $ans
```